# Оптимизация алгоритма подсчета числа уникальных значений по модулю

Tags: c++, алгоритм, оптимизация, stl, производительность

На первый взгляд задача кажется не сложной: получить к-во уникальных целочисленных значений по модулю из исходного контейнера. Первое, что пришло в голову - свалить все по абсолютной величине в сет и посмотреть его размер:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

size_t getUniqueByModuleItemCount(const std::vector<int>& input)
{
    std::set<unsigned> unique;

    for(int item : input) {
        unique.insert(abs(item));
    }

    return unique.size();
}

int main() {

    std::vector<int> srcVec = {1, -4, 3, 2, -12, 0, 4, 17, -2, -2, -3, 13, 7};
    size_t uniqueItemCount = getUniqueByModuleItemCount(srcVec);
    std::cout << "Unique items count by absolute value is " << uniqueItemCount << std::endl;
}
```

Это работает, но, очевидно, сложность такого алгоритма `O(N*lnN)` (проход по всем элементам исходного контейнера со вставкой в дерево, каждая вставка lnN). Соответственно вопрос - есть ли идеи как оптимизировать сложность данного алгоритм до `O(N)`?

Comment: использовать unordered_set?

Comment: все гениальное просто. спасибо, самому не пришло в голову

Comment: Думаю, хоть это и `O(N*lnN)`, но по *реальному времени работы* быстрее будет сортировка вектора + uniq...

Comment: @Harry спасибо, я посмотрю вечером на разном наборе данных все три варианта, включая исходный

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Я тут провел небольшой эксперимент...

Рандомно созданный вектор из `N` чисел с положительными и отрицательными значениями, с использованием разных контейнеров:

```
size_t usingSet(const std::vector<int>& input)
{
    std::set<unsigned> unique;
    for(int item : input) {
        unique.insert(abs(item));
    }
    return unique.size();
}

size_t usingHash(const std::vector<int>& input)
{
    std::unordered_set<unsigned> unique;
    unique.reserve(input.size());
    for(int item : input) {
        unique.insert(abs(item));
    }
    return unique.size();
}

size_t usingVec(const std::vector<int>& input)
{
    std::vector<unsigned> uniq;
    uniq.reserve(input.size());
    for(int item : input) {
        uniq.push_back(abs(item));
    }
    sort(uniq.begin(),uniq.end());
    return unique(uniq.begin(),uniq.end()) - uniq.begin();
}
```

По 1000 раз выясняем количество уникальных элементов. Время в микросекундах, понятно, что плюс-минус... но для оценки вполне годится. Округлять не стал, думаю, самим в уме в секунды-миллисекунды прикинуть несложно.

```
                            Set          Hash        Vector
-----------------------------------------------------------
N =         10:             790          1256           253
N =        100:            8304          8243          1192
N =       1000:          130070         78354         27573
N =      10000:         1543452        757059        498093
N =     100000:        14545110       4232742       6182957
N =    1000000:       127603400      27039847      61045621
```

Итак, вектор начинает проигрывать между 10 и 100 тысячами хэшу. При малых значениях хэш проигрывает даже `set`'у, сравниваясь на уровне 100 элементов. Дальше `set` безнадежно проигрывает всем - как я понимаю, не только из-за `O(N*ln N)`, но и из-за большого количества перераспределений памяти (члена `reserve()` у него, в отличие от хэша и вектора, нет).

Как попроще проверить потребляемую память, я что-то не придумал, но понятно, что тут вектор всем даст фору :)

Словом, самый грустный вариант - `set`, его использовать не имеет смысла вообще. При небольших размерах - до десятков тысяч - лучше брать вектор, а дальше смотреть, что важнее - скорость или память.

Все это на Visual C++ 2015, 32 bit.
Для Visual C++ 2010, 32 bit преимущества вектора видны еще ярче :) И хэш тут вообще проигрывает:

```
                            Set          Hash        Vector
-----------------------------------------------------------
N =         10:             813          1459           223
N =        100:            8688         10795          1448
N =       1000:          135905        102716         29086
N =      10000:         1623786       1068878        519483
N =     100000:        18334735       8822607       6316194
N =    1000000:       179540082      83667899      61899536
```

Кто хочет повторить для других компиляторов - you are welcome...

Кстати, с вектором можно еще оптимизировать - поскольку нам нужно **только количество** уникальных элементов - можно не использовать `unique` с его перетасовкой в памяти, а просто пройти и пересчитать те элементы, у которых соседние не такие же.

*Update*. Я предполагал, что количество совпадений невелико; в комментариях меня поправили. Я все же не стал делать количество уникальных элементов мизерным - рука не лежит - но заполнил массив так:

```
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    src.push_back((rand()%(N/5))*(i%2 ? 1 : -1));
```

Т.е. совпадений достаточно много, но все же уникальных элементов - `O(N)`

Результаты для 2015, миллиона дожидаться не стал:

```
                            Set          Hash        Vector
-----------------------------------------------------------
N =         10:             279           760           229
N =        100:            2693          2785          1185
N =       1000:           53087         24940         26121
N =      10000:          806965        273205        472123
N =     100000:        12350458       3440321       6006227
```

Граница несколько сместилась вниз, но принцип остался: `set` пролетает, но бьет хэш на массивах до 100; хэш начинает лидировать где-то с 1000, а не с 10000.

В пределе, когда все `N` элементов - единицы, результаты почти парадоксальные:

```
                            Set          Hash        Vector
-----------------------------------------------------------
N =         10:             200           895           219
N =        100:             888          1840           493
N =       1000:            7676         10020          2778
N =      10000:           73524        102685         25881
N =     100000:          733058       1167238        259100
N =    1000000:         7396809      11645557       3561249
```

вектор, и только вектор! Хэш в этом случае проигрывает даже `set`'у.

Все, времени заниматься экспериментами просто больше нет; кто хочет - продолжайте :)

*Update2* - В своей "Optimized C++" Гюнтерот недаром пишет, что `unordered_set` хотя и дает эффект, но совершенно не тот, которого следовало бы ожидать, читая, как его расхваливают :) Цитата из книги: *The hash table `std::unordered_map` is faster than `std::map`, but not by the order-of-magnitude difference that its reputation suggests*.

Comment: безусловно, даже считать не надо. У любого дерева затраты памяти как минимум в 2 раза выше чем у массива. (а обычно для динамических деревьев в 4). У хеш-таблиц затраты памяти зависят от коэффициента загрузки (не помню сколько там по умолчанию, 30% чтоли). А проверить можно грубо через диспетчер задач или логируя вызовы new и new[]

Comment: а с 2010 ms что-то явно не так... Ну не может увеличение размера в 10 раз, увеличивать время работы меньше чем в 10... Похоже проблемы запуска WoW64... Интересно ваше мнение. Кстати чем вы генерировали массив исходный?

Comment: @pavel Вот код http://vpaste.net/jKv2n - `muTimer` просто использует `QueryPerformanceCounter` и `QueryPerformanceFrequency`. Для 2010 пришлось переписать циклы через итераторы типа `for(auto item = input.begin(), end = input.end(); item != end; ++item) {
        unique.insert(abs(*item));
    }` и убрать `reserve` из `unordered_set`.

Comment: @pavel Что до того, почему так - ну, может, меньшее количество перераспределений памяти? Я не Гюнтерот (автор "Optimized C++"), такого опыта нет, не объясню :) Как тот чукча из анекдота - что вижу, о том и пою...

Comment: а теперь замените rand() на rand()%10 и результаты меняются на противоположные)

Comment: Ну, я считал, что у нас все-таки совпадения - редкость :) OK, сейчас пересчитаю и добавлю.

Comment: кстати а компилятор может сделать оптимизацию `sum += usingSet(src);` вызвав её 1 раз, на основании того что `const std::vector<int>& input` + нету модификаци глобальных переменных? Да и сумма ещё нигде не используется...

Comment: @pavel Даже если и может (хотя вряд ли: для этого ему надо быть ну чересчур умным...) - то это все равно играет роль только для абсолютных значений времен, но не для их отношений - просто выше погрешность измерений. P.S. Подставил `repeat=1` - просвистело примерно на порядок быстрее, так что нет, не оптимизирует...

Comment: @pavel Пардон, конечно же, в смысле, на три порядка!

Comment: @Harry спасибо за развёрнутый анализ. Единственное, что касается предположения о проигрывания сета из-за перераспределения памяти, которого нет у вектора и Херша из-за своевременной резервации памяти - тут я думаю нет. Сету перераспределять память просто незачем, так его узлы связаны указателями и могут располагаться в памяти совершенно произвольно. Тут конечно проседает из-за логарифмической вставки. Вектор в этом плане конечно сильно выигрывает и даже, как показали ваши эксперименты, финальный quick sort не способен сильно повлиять на конечный результат.

Comment: Я имею в виду динамическое выделение памяти для каждого узла `set`. Ну, и освобождение тоже. А это все, увы, реально дорогостоящие операции... Плюс может быть (но может и не быть) эффект ухудшения локальности кэша.

Comment: @Harry попробую обернуть инт в маленький классик с подсчетом к-ва операций сравнения айтемов в варианте с сетом и вектором при сортировке, думаю результат будет прямо пропорционален вашим замерам времени выполнения