# Как подсчитать количество уникальных слов в массиве?

Tags: c++

Насколько я понимаю, можно разбить массив на слова с помощью функции `strtok`,
не могу придумать, как подсчитать количество именно уникальных слов.

Comment: Используйте map

Comment: "количество уникальных слов в массиве" В массиве чего?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Применять `set` или `unordered_set` для **небольших** наборов - палить из пушки по воробьям. Кстати, вопрос сравнения методов выделения уникальных записей (правда, не для строк) уже поднимался и рассматривался [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/573451/195342).

Здесь эффективнее записать все указатели на слова в массив, отсортировать и вернуть уникальные, что-то вроде

```
int main()
{
    const char * delimeters = " \t,."; // Решите сами, что вам нужно
    char s[] = "aaa bbb ccc ddd aaa ddd ccc ggg";
    vector<char*> ptrs;
    for(char* w = strtok(s,delimeters); w; w = strtok(nullptr,delimeters))
        ptrs.push_back(w);
    sort(ptrs.begin(), ptrs.end(),
         [](const char* a,const char* b){ return strcmp(a,b) < 0; });
    cout << distance(ptrs.begin(),
                     unique(ptrs.begin(),ptrs.end(),
                            [](const char* a,const char* b){ return strcmp(a,b) == 0; }))
        << endl;
}
```

Но, как я понимаю, сейчас ваши преподы требуют от вас простых решений, не использующих все эти премудрости с STL. Например, такие:

```
int main()
{
    const char * delimeters = " \t,."; // Решите сами, что вам нужно
    char s[] = "aaa bbb ccc ddd aaa ddd ccc ggg";
    char * words[50]; // Ну, заведомо больше, чем слов...
    int n = 0;
    for(char* w = strtok(s,delimeters); w; w = strtok(nullptr,delimeters))
        words[n++] = w;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        ++count;
        for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
            if (strcmp(words[i],words[j]) == 0)
            {
                --count;
                break;
            }
    }
    cout << count << endl;
}
```

При небольших наборах слов работать будет очень быстро...

Answer (score 1):

Наивная реализация может выглядеть как-то так:

```
char arr[] = "aaa bbb,aa, bbb\ta aa bb"; //исходный массив со словами
unordered_set<string> uniqWords;//сюда будем вставлять слова - set это такой контейнер, который хранит только уникальные значения
char *token = strtok(arr, " \t,.:;\r\n!?"); //начинаем разбивку на токены: слова могут разделяться пробелами, табуляцией, знаками препинания
while (token != NULL)
{
    uniqWords.insert(token);
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
}

//выводим кол-во уникальных
cout << "Unique words = " << uniqWords.size() << '\n';
```

Полный пример можно запустить [здесь](https://ideone.com/m49jaw)